# pagination vuejs 3 and laravel with bootstrap

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, laravel-pagination

I´m trying to build paginate with laravel-vue-pagination and i can´t to show my links... I´m reading documentation and showing examples but i don´t know that i´m doing wrong. I want paginate result from my API resources:

```
return ListingResource::collection(Listing::where('cp', '=', $value)->simplePaginate(15));
```

I´m doing this in my `API controller` and result it´s:

```
"updated_at":"2022-05-31T07:15:08.000000Z"}],"links":{"first":"http:\/\/www.crm.local:8081\/api\/listingApi\/getRegister\/cp\/18519?page=1","last":null,"prev":null,"next":"http:\/\/www.crm.local:8081\/api\/listingApi\/getRegister\/cp\/18519?page=2"},"meta":{"current_page
....
```

in my `app.js` i want globally component:

```
import { Bootstrap4Pagination } from 'laravel-vue-pagination';
```

And including in my `apps`:

```
const app4 = createApp({
    components:{
        nAsignedCalls,
        Bootstrap4Pagination
    }
})
app4.mount('#app4')
```

and in my component:

```
<Bootstrap4Pagination :data="valor" @pagination-change-page="getResults" />

<script setup>
    import { defineProps } from 'vue';
    
    
    const props = defineProps({
        valor: {
            type: Object,
            required: true
        },
    });
    
    const getResults = async (page = 1) => {
        const response = await fetch(`/api/listingApi/getRegister?page=${page}`);
        props.valor = await response.json();
    }

    getResults();
        
</script>
```

but, when load my page my web browser console return:

```
VM2625:1 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<link rel="... is not valid JSON
```

and when i load my registers web browser console return:

```
Failed to resolve component: Bootstrap4Pagination
If this is a native custom element, make sure to exclude it from component resolution via compilerOptions.isCustomElement. 
  at <NAsignedCalls valor= (15) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}] > 
  at <FormTelemarketing> 
  at <App>
```

I don´t know that i´m doing wrong.

**UPDATE**

I've got change my code to eliminate my errors and pass how property to paginate my links and in console now not show any problems or warnings. But i can´t show pagination...

```
const links = ref({})
const resp = await axios.get(`/api/listingApi/getRegister/${param_search.value["parameter"]}/${param_search.value["value"]}`)
            registers.value =  resp.data.data
            links.value = resp.data.links

<!-- SEND PROP LINKS TO MY COMPONENT -->

<nAsignedCalls :valor="registers" :links="links"/>  

<!-- PAGINATION IN MY COMPONENT -->

<Bootstrap5Pagination :data="links" @pagination-change-page="getResults" />
        </table>
    </div>
</template>
  
<script setup>
    import { defineProps } from 'vue';
    import { Bootstrap5Pagination } from 'laravel-vue-pagination';
    
    const props = defineProps({
        valor: {
            type: Object,
            required: true
        },
        links: {
            type: Object,
            required: true
        }
    });
    
    const getResults = async (page = 1) => {
        const response = await fetch(`/api/listingApi/getRegister?page=${page}`);
        props.valor = await JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response));
    }

    getResults();
        
</script>
```

**update 2**

i´ve got fill my table with pagination, i change my code to this:

```
$pagination = $request->get('pagination');

            $pagination = ($pagination != "") ? $pagination : 10;
            
            if($parameter == 'address'){
                return ListingResource::collection(Listing::where('address', '=', $value)->simplePaginate($pagination));
            }else if($parameter == 'city'){
                return ListingResource::collection(Listing::where('city', '=', $value)->simplePaginate($pagination));
            }else if($parameter == 'cp'){
                return ListingResource::collection(Listing::where('cp', '=', $value)->paginate($pagination));
            }
```

when i clicked my button not selectiong pagintaion number, default it´s 10 registers, but in console return this:

```
traneous non-props attributes (links) were passed to component but could not be automatically inherited because component renders fragment or text root nodes. 
  at <NAsignedCalls valor= (10) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}] links= {first: 'http://www.crm.local:8081/api/listingApi/getRegister/cp/18519?page=1', last: 'http://www.crm.local:8081/api/listingApi/getRegister/cp/18519?page=16', prev: null, next: 'http://www.crm.local:8081/api/listingApi/getRegister/cp/18519?page=2'} > 
  at <FormTelemarketing> 
  at <App>
```

i don´t know very well how i can solve this problem in my vue i change my code:

```
const props = defineProps({
        valor: {
            type: Object,
            required: true
        },
        data:{
            links: {
                type: Array,
                required: true
            }
        }
        
    });

<div class="row justify-content-end">
        pagination
        <Bootstrap4Pagination :data="links" @pagination-change-page="getResults" />
    </div>
```

Thanks for readme and help me. Sorry for my bad english

Comment: *"<link rel="... is not valid JSON* You API is broken. It does return a HTML page instead of JSON

Comment: *Failed to resolve component: Bootstrap4Pagination* your component was not found.

Comment: @Tolbxela i´m sorry for my explanation. I updated my question in ```UPDATE``` section

Comment: @Tolbxela i updated my question, if you can show it.. and we can continue... Thanks